# Two different load balancers for different domains

Tags: amazon-web-services, load-balancing, amazon-elb

I was wondering if it's possible to have two different load balancers for different domains. Say for instance, an application load balancer (alb) for "www.example.com" and a network load balancer (nlb) for "api.example.com". I'm actually planning to pass all the web traffic to alb and all the mobile traffic to nlb. Also, alb has the ability to redirect http to https. So, what's the best practice here? I'm very new to all this. Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Yes, you can use that. But do you have a reason for having both alb and nlb? For example, a need to pass though **ssl connections to your backend servers** or a **static ip**? Also having both nlb and alb could be more costly than just having alb.

Comment: The reason would be - I can redirect http to https for web traffic. Also, redirecting is not available on NLB since it's layer 4. For mobile traffic though I only need TLS and no redirect needed. I'm serving mobile traffic on api.example.com, where as web traffic on example.com. I'm using port 80 internally i.e. from load balancers to backend.

Comment: I'm not sure actually. This is just based on my current understanding. Is NLB more suited to use internally and ALB facing clients?

Comment: Both NLB and ALB can be used as public ones. Its depends on your requirements. Though NLB has more uses as private LB. NLB is the only one which can be used for API Gateway VPCLinks or VPC Pirvate Links. So for these use cases, there is no choice, except NLB.

Answer (score 1):

You can have many load balancer. I would suggest you use an ALB for HTTP based traffic.

ALB have many routing rules that may be advantageous, for example you could use a single ALB but direct traffic to different target groups based on the host header.

Great blog post here: https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-advanced-request-routing-for-aws-application-load-balancers/

Comment: So, is it not best practice to use nlb for client facing?

Comment: For a http application, you’d tend to go with an ALB. There will always be exceptions to the rule but I’d say go with ALB